# UITableView not scrolling after i did this

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I'm new to iOS developing. I have a UITableViewCell which has three buttons and they were not appearing to be pressed to touch. I implemented the following code. The pressing appeared to have been solved but the scrolling have been disabled. Here's my code to make buttons appear to be pressed on touch. The loop in the code is important otherwise the table will not behave the way I want it to. Here's my code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"customCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UILabel *textLabel = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:5];

    switch ([indexPath section]) {
        case 0:
            textLabel.text = [patientRoom objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
            break;
        case 1:
            textLabel.text = [patientsBathroom objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
            break;
    }

    if (shown){
        if (selectedIndexPath.row == indexPath.row)
            comments.hidden = NO;
    }
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    // Configure the cell...

    for (id obj in cell.subviews){
        if ([NSStringFromClass([obj class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellScrollView"]){
            UIScrollView *scroll = (UIScrollView *) obj;
            scroll.delaysContentTouches = NO;
            break;
        } 
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: So you are trying to put a scroll view in a UITableviewCell?

Comment: i have this tableview that i am working on with a cell that has 3 buttons in its contentView. when i click on that button its not showing that touch down animation thingy. for that i have to hold my finger for a while. to bypass that i added that loop in which i stopped the delay which was happening from scroll view. now that touch down animation works fine but scrolling has been disabled.